# Re.sub python- Replacing more items at the the same time

Tags: regex

I have to substitute a range of accented characters in a string with the respective non accented letters.
I was thinking of using re.sub but I have no clue of how to substitute more items (each one with a different item) at the same time.
So to be clearer:

```
import re
re.sub(r'è|ù|ò|à','e,u,o,a',string).
```

First of all is this allowed in Python so to avoid to make a separate line for each letter?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`re.sub()` can accept a function as the replacement, so you can do something like the following:

```
reps = dict(zip('èùòà', 'euoa'))
re.sub(r'è|ù|ò|à', lambda m: reps[m.group(0)], some_string)
```

Example:

```
>>> re.sub(r'è|ù|ò|à', lambda m: reps[m.group(0)], 'à ò ù è')
'a o u e'
```